# How to configure relationship between classes in an existing db in EF Code First from Database?

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, fluent, entity-framework-6.1

I read a number of posts from Julie Lerman and here on SO trying to figure out how to configure the relationship between 2 entities. I used EF Code First to generate the classes from an existing db over which I have no control and that already has a lot of data. In one table `PostId` is a `guid` while `PostRowID` is the `PK`. When I modify the classes to try and get a relationship I end up with the error `Invalid object name 'dbo.be_PostTagbe_Posts'.` Most if not all of the examples seem to deal with Code First and not Code First from DB. How do I map the relationship between the 2 classes? Or do I need a 3rd table to map the relations?

I also looked at the fluent api and got this far:

```
modelBuilder.Entity(Of be_Posts)().HasMany(Function(a) 
a.be_PostTag).WithMany().Map(Function(x)
x.MapLeftKey("PostID")x.MapRightKey("PostID") 'Don't know what to do next
```

I am trying to use the `Include` syntax when this happens. I added the 2 ICollection properties but I suspect since the db deviates from EF convention that's why the EF cannot figure out the relationship.

```
Partial Public Class be_Posts

    <Key>
    Public Property PostRowID As Integer

    Public Property BlogID As Guid

    Public Property PostID As Guid

    'Other Stuff

    Public Property be_PostTag As ICollection(Of be_PostTag)

End Class
```

And

```
Partial Public Class be_PostTag
    <Key>
    Public Property PostTagID As Integer

    Public Property BlogID As Guid

    Public Property PostID As Guid

    'Other stuff

    Public Property be_Posts As ICollection(Of be_Posts)

End Class
```

And the include:

```
  Using db As New BetterBlogContext
     post = db.be_Posts.OrderByDescending(Function(x)
     x.DateCreated).Include("be_PostTag").Where(Function(p) p.PostRowID
     = id).FirstOrDefault
   End Using
```

Comment: What does this look like on the db? Is there a join table?

Comment: No join table for the tags and posts. be_PostTag has `PostTagID as int, PostID as uniqueidentifier, BlogID as uniqueidentifier, PostID as uniqueidentified and Tag as NVARCHAR(50)`

Comment: With your existing code you've mapped a many-to-many relationship so a join table named "be_PostTagbe_Posts" is expected. What is the intended relationship between these two entities?

Comment: One post can have many tags and many tags can be associated with many posts. But I'D be happy if i can just get one post with many tags working for now.

Comment: You say that you used Code First but that means that you write the code and the EF generates the database.  Do you actually mean Database First?

Comment: No, as I said in the title, I used Code First From Database as in the 4th option in the Entity Data Model Wizard window in VS2013. The one that generates classes from the Database without the EDMX file.

Comment: Got the relations between the tags and posts sorted - added the collection properties and then had to directly create the tables using SQL Management Studio that EF needed to make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it figure out without using Fluent API. After I added the 2 ICollection Properties, I had to manually add the table Entity Framework needed with the appropriate 2 columns to handle the relationship. Ran a SQL command to copy the needed data and everything worked.